# SqlAlchemy connection string using pymssql

Tags: sqlalchemy, connection-string, freetds, pymssql

Is there an equivalent of `odbc_connect` in `pymssql` using `freeTDS` driver?

For example using `pyodbc` I can use connect within the connection string itself and then pass all required parameters:

`conn_string = ("mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}".format(parameters)`

Is it possible to use `&connect={}` within the string using `pymssql` & `freeTDS` in `SQLAlchemy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because `odbc_connect=` is part of the pyodbc driver code in SQLAlchemy and the pymssql driver code has no corresponding option. That said, pymssql was actively supported in SQLAlchemy until recently, so if you need to pass any extra options to pymssql there is probably a way to do it. Check [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pymssql) for details.